# Get a Place Object From String Address where User Clicks on Map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-places-api

**Some background**:
I have a map where I allow the user to click and **select a place**. Then I am getting the address from the place where they clicked.

**What I want to do:** Using that address, which is a `String`, **I want to get details about that place** by using the ***new*** Google Map Places API.

**I'm attempting to do this with the code below**

```
//Make the Autocomplete request builder with the String address
FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.Builder requestBuilder =
                    FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.builder()
                            .setQuery(address)
                            .setTypeFilter(TypeFilter.ADDRESS);
placesClient = Places.createClient(getApplicationContext());

//Create the Autocomplete Task
Task<FindAutocompletePredictionsResponse> task =
                    placesClient.findAutocompletePredictions(requestBuilder.build());

task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FindAutocompletePredictionsResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(final FindAutocompletePredictionsResponse findAutocompletePredictionsResponse) {
        //Use the response to get a list of Predictions
        List<AutocompletePrediction> list = findAutocompletePredictionsResponse.getAutocompletePredictions();
            if (list.isEmpty() || list == null) {

            } else {
                //Get the first Autocomplete prediction and later, it's ID.
                AutocompletePrediction ap = list.get(0);
                //Provide a list of Place Fields that I want to retrieve.         
                List<Place.Field> placeFields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.ADDRESS);

                //Make the request to fetch the place using the Place ID obtained from the Autocomplete prediction.
                FetchPlaceRequest request = FetchPlaceRequest.builder(ap.getPlaceId(), placeFields).build();
                placesClient = Places.createClient(getApplicationContext());

                //Using the Place ID from the Autocomplete prediction, make a request to fetch places.
                placesClient.fetchPlace(request).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FetchPlaceResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(FetchPlaceResponse fetchPlaceResponse) {
                        //Use the response to get the Place Object
                        Place place = fetchPlaceResponse.getPlace();
                        //Display the results from the Place Object
                        displayResults("\n-----------------\nName: " + place.getName() + "\nAddress: " + place.getAddress());
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    //......
                });
            }
       }
});
task.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    //......
});
```

**Problem**: The problem is that when I do this and use `place.getName()`, instead of displaying the location's name, as it should, it displays the first part of the address like the street number and name. Additionally, other Fields like the phone number and opening hours are null.

**Does anybody know how I can get the `Place` Object from the `String` address?
Getting details about the place where the user clicks is the most important feature of my Android app.**

**I am using the new `Places API` since the `Place Details` and `Place Picker` are now deprecated.**

Comment: does the api get you a placeID ?

Comment: @HossamEldeenOnsy It does give me a `placeID`, but the funny thing is that in my code, I am using that `Place ID` to `fetchPlace`, but it still doesn't give me the proper name, and phone number, and other fields besides the address.

Comment: okay have you tried using the place details api ?  `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/output?parameters`
here is the link https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details
if you have it would be great to show me the snippet where you used it , if not then i believe this api is what you are actually seeking

Comment: @HossamEldeenOnsy On the page for Place Details for Android, it says that there is a deprecation notice and that 

"The Google Play Services version of the Places SDK for Android (in Google Play Services 16.0.0) is deprecated as of January 29, 2019, and will be turned off on July 29, 2019."
I am using the new Places API.

Comment: in the migration part noted here https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration 

`String placeId = "INSERT_PLACE_ID_HERE";

List<Place.Field> placeFields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME);

FetchPlaceRequest request = FetchPlaceRequest.builder(placeId, placeFields)
        .build();`
you are required to use fetchPlace(request) 
and calling it will have a callback 
addOnSuccessListener() to handle the FetchPlaceResponse. A single Place result is returned. which is what you want correct ?

Comment: @HossamEldeenOnsy yes it is. That's what I've done in my code, ***which I've posted above with comments for each step***. I am using `fetchPlaceRequest` and in the request, I am providing the `placeID` with `AutocompletePrediction.getPlaceID()`. **However, the problem that I am getting is in the `FetchPlaceResponse`, in the `Place` that I am getting, all the `Fields` besides address are null and `place.getName()` returns the first part of the address *(street number and name)*.** Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196078/discussion-between-hossam-eldeen-onsy-and-ishaan-javali).